# Excel VBA geocoding response invalid

Tags: google-maps, vba, geocoding

I use this script to get geocodes for any address in germany:

```
Public Function getGoogleMapsGeocode(sAddr As String) As String

Dim xhrRequest As XMLHTTP60
Dim sQuery As String
Dim domResponse As DOMDocument60
Dim ixnStatus As IXMLDOMNode
Dim ixnLat As IXMLDOMNode
Dim ixnLng As IXMLDOMNode


' Use the empty string to indicate failure
getGoogleMapsGeocode = ""

Set xhrRequest = New XMLHTTP60
sQuery = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address="
sQuery = sQuery & Replace(sAddr, " ", "+")
xhrRequest.Open "GET", sQuery, True
xhrRequest.send

Set domResponse = New DOMDocument60
domResponse.LoadXML xhrRequest.responseText
Set ixnStatus = domResponse.SelectSingleNode("//status")

If (ixnStatus.Text <> "OK") Then
    'Exit Function
End If

Set ixnLat = domResponse.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat")
Set ixnLng = domResponse.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng")

getGoogleMapsGeocode = ixnLat.Text & ", " & ixnLng.Text

End Function
```

When I type the query string into the browser it returns a valid xml response with the geocodes. If I let vba do it, I get an error. Is there something I should know?

responseText :

```
 "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>INVALID_REQUEST</status>
</GeocodeResponse>
" : String : Modul8.getGoogleMapsGeocode
```

Comment: It worked for me without error.

Comment: With the function or the request just in the browser?

Comment: I pasted your function into a standard module, added a reference to Microsoft XML 6.0, and I got coordinates back when I put in my address. It did error on the responsetext because it hadn't finished loading. OK, so I lied, it worked for me with one error. But I debugged, then F5 to keep running and by that time the xml had loaded. I don't get "Invalid Request".